# Jukebox - I know what a Box is but what exactly is a Juke?

Tags: nouns

What exactly is a Juke?  I only know this word if:  1) it's attached to -box;  2) an athlete confuses his/her opponent with a series of moves.
But what is its exact origin?  JEP

Comment: You can [look it up](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=juke&allowed_in_frame=0) and [sort it out](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=jukebox&allowed_in_frame=0).

Answer (score 2):

The *juke* in jukebox comes from *jook joint*, a slang term for a roadhouse or brothel.

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=jukebox) describes *jook* as having originated from a Gullah word meaning *wicked and disorderly*:

> jook joint "roadhouse" (1935), Black English slang, from juke, joog "wicked, disorderly," in Gullah (the creolized English of the coastlands of South Carolina, Georgia, and northern Florida), probably from Wolof and Bambara dzug "unsavory." Said to have originated in central Florida (see "A Note on Juke," Florida Review, vol. VII, no. 3, spring 1938). The spelling with a -u- might represent a deliberate attempt to put distance between the word and its origins.